# Jquery, Chosen.js

Tags: jquery-chosen

Regarding chosen.js library, say I select a dropdown value "A" and then type in B as text, so now the search should be based on both A and B. The issue I am facing is how to read the text input B so that I can do manipulation on it.

{{listname}}

$('#multipleSelect').bind('input', '.chosen-search input', function(event){ alert('iam done'); });

Comment: did you tried anything so far?

Comment: <select chosen multiple name="multipleSelect" id="multipleSelect" class="chosen-select" ng-multiple="true" ng-model="searchfield" ng-change="changedValue(searchfield)">
                            <option ng-repeat="listname in searchassets" value="{{listname}}">{{listname}}</option>
                        </select>

Comment: you should mention that in your question with well formatting

Comment: so when you type something it only shows result from the dropdown values it has. If value is not found I want to search the text entered in database. i cant get the values of text entered.

Comment: $('#multipleSelect').bind('input', '.chosen-search input', function(event){ alert('iam done'); });

Comment: @gahan Can you please help